# Bootstrap radio button not shown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I used the below html for radio button in bootstrap

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
    Option two can be something else and selecting it will deselect option one
  </label>
</div>
```

Apart from label,no radio button is shown..

even         `<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">`

doesnt show a radio button.What can be the issue

Comment: We cant tell you unless we see your CSS. We can only imagine

Comment: I am using the bootstraps css itself

Comment: Look at this fiddle with your own code... http://www.bootply.com/129198 I can see the radio...

Answer (score 3):

If your radio buttons are not showing, chances are somewhere in your css you have the following code:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
```

The **display: none;** bit is what is making your radio buttons invisible.

Comment: This could apply to a fairly narrow group of users experiencing this issues

Answer (score 0):

If your radio buttons are not showing, chances are the opacity may set to '0'. so you can use below CSS code.

```
  input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 4 it was class `.custom-control-input` and `position: absolute`:

```
.custom-control-input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1.22rem;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

This might help to get it displayed:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```